# A problem with missing attribute with mps

Tags: python, error-handling, module, mps

I have a certain problem with a certain error "module 'torch' has no attribute 'has_mps'". I followed tutorial on how to install it on github page RVC-GUI, even when I done everything correctly.

I know someone here had a similar problem like me, but that resolution of that problem didn't work. Also I don't know if this information is relevant or not but I use CPU and GPU from AMD. I will be really greatfull if someone knows how to resolve this problem. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apz4u.png)

I tried uninstalling and installing torchvision, but it didn't help.